# Issue with a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have the following form line:

```
<input class="form_input" type="text" id="Fname" placeholder="First Name" minlength="2" maxlength="30" onkeyup="restrict('name')"/>
```

And the associated JavaScript code:

```
function restrict(elem) {
    var tf = $('#' + elem)
    var rx = new RegExp()
    if (elem === 'email') {
        rx = /[^a-z0-9@_.-]/gi
    } else if (elem === 'username') {
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi
    } else if (elem === 'phone') {
        rx = /[0-9()-]/gi
    } else if (elem === 'address') {
        rx = /[^a-z0-9_.,-]/gi
    } else if (elem === 'city') {
        rx = /[^a-z.-]/gi
    } else if (elem === 'name') {
        rx = /[^a-z.-]/gi
    }
    tf.val(tf.val().replace(rx, ''))
}
```

When I try and run the code I get the following error and I can't seem to figure out why after reviewing it many times...

```
TypeError: tf.val(...) is undefined
```

Yet everything is defined, so I'm really puzzled.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id="Fname"` ... `onkeyup="restrict('name')"`

```
function restrict(elem) {
    var tf = $('#' + elem)
```

There is no element with id `name`.

---

I suggest you also look at `pattern` attribute on your input for validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

Your input has an id of "Fname", not "name". Change its id to name to fix the issue.

```
<input class="form_input" type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name" minlength="2" maxlength="30" onkeyup="restrict('name')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function like `restrict(this.id)`